# fire hover event on multiple views

Tags: android

I have 50 views as children in my layout.
I want that when I drag over (hover) on each view without releasing the finger all touched view to change their color.

I don't know witch listener should I use to do this.
I tried using onHover(), but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` like this

```
yourview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
  Log.d("TouchTest", "Finger touched");
} 
else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
  Log.d("TouchTest", "Finger being dragged");
}
else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
  Log.d("TouchTest", "finger lifted from screen");
}
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but when I implement setOnTouchListener on every child view onTouch return me only first touched view even I'm on another child.  Thanks

Comment: @Jovan in this case you will need to implement a custom `recyclerview` like this https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview